# An issue with Yii2 pager(showing fewer records than should)

Tags: php, listview, model-view-controller, pagination, yii2

I have a problem with Yii2 pagination. I use ListView widget to show data. Also I am using SetSort in my model to sort data.
My search model code:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Items::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
        $dataProvider->setSort([
            'defaultOrder' => ['position' => SORT_ASC],
            'attributes' => [
                'position' => [
                    'asc' => ['items.is_top'=>SORT_ASC,'items.position' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'By popularity',
                ],
                'pricerup' => [
                    'asc' => ['prices.price' => SORT_ASC],
                    'label' => 'Exprensive to cheap'
                ],
                'pricerdown' => [
                    'asc' => ['prices.price' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'Cheap to expensive'
                ],
            ]
        ]); 
        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            $query->joinWith(['prices']);
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'discount' => $this->discount,
            'present_id' => $this->present_id,
            'is_top' => $this->is_top,
            'manufacturer_id' => $this->manufacturer_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'taste', $this->taste])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country', $this->country])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slug', $this->slug])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'short_desc', $this->short_desc])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'thumbnail', $this->thumbnail]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

I know that this is not a very good decision to divide DESC and ASC logic for price, but this is needed for current design. My controller code:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ItemsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'searchModel'=>$searchModel,
        ]);
    }
```

As I said, in view I use ListView. This is my view code:

```
 <? Pjax::begin(['id' => 'items', 'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]);?>
                               <?
                               $dataProvider->pagination = [
                                   'defaultPageSize' => 8,
                               ];
                               echo ListView::widget( [
                                   'id'=>'items',
                                   'pager'        => [

                                       'firstPageLabel'    => "",
                                       'disabledPageCssClass'=>'swiper-button-disabled',
                                       'lastPageLabel'     => "",
                                       'nextPageLabel'     => ">",
                                       'prevPageLabel'     => "<",
                                       'maxButtonCount'=>0,
                                       'nextPageCssClass'=>'total-button-next',                                     'prevPageCssClass'=>'total-button-prev',
                                       'options'=>['id'=>'poplinks','class'=>'col-md-12 total-slider-orders margin-right-null padding-left-right-yes total-down-arrow']

                                   ],
                                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                                'itemView' => '_item',
                                   'summary'=>'',

                               ] );
                               Pjax::end();?>
```

As a result I get something like this:[image: ListView without last element]

As you can see, it doesn't have last element on the first page, on the next pages everything is ok. I think that this is something with the offset,limit. Can someone tell me, where is an error? Thanks!

Comment: check the resulting query for fetching items in debug module and try to execute it in db directly to make sure that it returns desired number of records

Comment: @Tony thanks for reply, but dump of the query shows only "SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` LEFT JOIN `prices` ON `items`.`id` = `prices`.`item_id`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of many relation, AR show item with two prices as two items, so it show 7 items on page instead of 8. Resolved it just by adding to search model one line:

```
$query->groupBy('items.id');
```